# How to get report data from Google Ad Manager in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I am not sure if this is an appropriate question in StackOverflow, sorry if it is not.

I want to create a React app(an admin dashboard) that I can fetch the report data from Google Ad Manager. I found an official YouTube channel that shows the API fetching from Google Ad Manager API here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLKByxjzUC-N8bM-bzhyzNu-PlgefTwUE9

But it seems, it does not show a way to have it in React and I could not found better sources for it. It would also be great if you share some sources, YouTube videos etc. I searched a lot but could not find a good fit.